# How to properly escape html sent as data in jQuery's .ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, escaping

**UPDATE**: Once I looked at the problem in Firebug, I found my mistake immediately. And it was an embarrassing unmatched double quote that I must have deleted somehow. I had been using Chrome's developer window. Very sorry for using up your resources. But, lesson learned! ("I hope.)

What is the best way for me to escape html characters that I want to send to my server? I am using jQuery, .ajax(), and jsonp.

I'm writing a bookmarklet which sends parts of the current page's html to my server. Here is the ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.my_server.com/file.php?callback=?',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: { someHtml: escape(jQuery(this).html().substring(0,1000)) },
    success: function() { // stuff },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','text/html');
                },
    error: function() { // stuff }
});
```

I need to use JSONP and therefore I can't use POST, and this is why I'm truncating the html data. Things work if the html is "nice", but if it contains characters javascript doesn't like, then I have problems. I fixed my ' problem by using escape(), but now I think I'm having newline and tab problems.

Chrome's dev console gives me the same error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

which I assume means some character is causing things to break out of javascript. I have tried the following: escape(), encodeURI/Component(), serialize(), text(), but nothing has worked yet. At first, I didn't use beforeSend, but thought I should try it, but no difference.

Currently, I'm stuck with some html which has a line break, then a tab, then a couple of spaces. I have tried replacing these characters using replace():

```
... .substring(0,1000).replace(/(\r\n|[\r\n])/g,'')
```

I found this regex string on another site which is supposed to replace various combinations of carriage returns and line feeds.

I hope I've explained myself clearly enough. It's my first question at Stack Overflow so go easy on me. :)

Comment: Thx! Wish I didn't have to ask it though. Banging head against wall...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to escape or encode. jQuery will take care of properly URL encoding the data:

```
data: { someHtml: $(this).html().substring(0, 1000) },
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. It looks like my problem is related to something completely different, but I don't know what. I simplified the statememt to $(this).text() on a very simple test site and I got the same problem. Looking into it more now.

Comment: @SeanO, maybe the server side script you are posting to disallows some special characters in the request? For example this is the case for ASP.NET with things like `<` and `>`. You could use FireBug to analyze what's happening under the covers.

Comment: Apologies to everyone. This was caused by an utterly ridiculous syntax error (unclosed quotes) in my server-side php file. Going to get syntax-highlighting set up immediately.