# jquery sending data with escapes?

Tags: jquery

I heard that when i use  jQuery.ajax and sending data as object - it automatically  - escapes the chars.

where does it written ?
I didnt find it in Documentation

is it true ?

Comment: Yes it's true. If you can't find it in the documentation, dig in the source. EDIT: I have digged in the **[source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js)**: `s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );`

Comment: releated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231810/escaping-jquery-data-being-sent-via-post

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly escape html sent as data in jQuery's .ajax function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122298/how-to-properly-escape-html-sent-as-data-in-jquerys-ajax-function)

Comment: @RobW please convert your comment to answer so i can check it.

Comment: @DanEsparza I asked where is the documentation ... not How to do it.

Comment: From the [`jQuery.param()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/): *"Create a serialized representation of an array or object, suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request."* ... note the use of the word *suitable* which indicates that the result can directly be used in a URL and therefore it can be concluded that the data is properly encoded.  That `jQuery.param()` is used, can be found in the [`jQuery.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: @RoyiNamir - You're absolutely correct.  So sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the source code, a local function `add` is defined:

```
add = function( key, value ) {
   value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : value;
   s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
};
```

This function prepares any input by escaping the special characters. When an object is passed as an argument, the `buildParams` method is invoked, passing the just-defined `add` function:

```
for ( var prefix in a ) {
   buildParams( prefix, a[ prefix ], traditional, add );
}
```

Inside the *recursive function* `buildParams`, the `add` method is invoked for each object-parameter. The flavours differ, but are generally in the following format:

```
add( prefix, obj );
```

---

Relevant code, derived from **[the source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js)**:

```
    // Serialize an array of form elements or a set of
    // key/values into a query string
    param: function( a, traditional ) {
        var s = [],
            add = function( key, value ) {
                // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
                value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : value;
                s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
            };

        // Set traditional to true for jQuery <= 1.3.2 behavior.
        if ( traditional === undefined ) {
            traditional = jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional;
        }

        // If an array was passed in, assume that it is an array of form elements.
        if ( jQuery.isArray( a ) || ( a.jquery && !jQuery.isPlainObject( a ) ) ) {
            // Serialize the form elements
            jQuery.each( a, function() {
                add( this.name, this.value );
            });

        } else {
            // If traditional, encode the "old" way (the way 1.3.2 or older
            // did it), otherwise encode params recursively.
            for ( var prefix in a ) {
                buildParams( prefix, a[ prefix ], traditional, add );
            }
        }

        // Return the resulting serialization
        return s.join( "&" ).replace( r20, "+" );
    }
});

function buildParams( prefix, obj, traditional, add ) {
    if ( jQuery.isArray( obj ) ) {
        // Serialize array item.
        jQuery.each( obj, function( i, v ) {
            if ( traditional || rbracket.test( prefix ) ) {
                // Treat each array item as a scalar.
                add( prefix, v );

            } else {
                // If array item is non-scalar (array or object), encode its
                // numeric index to resolve deserialization ambiguity issues.
                // Note that rack (as of 1.0.0) can't currently deserialize
                // nested arrays properly, and attempting to do so may cause
                // a server error. Possible fixes are to modify rack's
                // deserialization algorithm or to provide an option or flag
                // to force array serialization to be shallow.
                buildParams( prefix + "[" + ( typeof v === "object" || jQuery.isArray(v) ? i : "" ) + "]", v, traditional, add );
            }
        });

    } else if ( !traditional && obj != null && typeof obj === "object" ) {
        // Serialize object item.
        for ( var name in obj ) {
            buildParams( prefix + "[" + name + "]", obj[ name ], traditional, add );
        }

    } else {
        // Serialize scalar item.
        add( prefix, obj );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is implicitly assumed.

In general, whenever you have a function that transmits data from an object or parameter, you can assume that the function will correctly escape / parameterize the data so that you can pass arbitrary strings.

Assuming that you're using well-written libraries (which jQuery is), you should only need to escape things when explicitly building strings.

For example, jQuery's `text()` function will automatically HTML-escape your text.