# jQuery load function escapes data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, escaping

I have a strange problem with the load function from jQuery. It escapes HTML content that jQuery gets back from the load function. I load HTML output from a PHP file into a div. I use this function:

```
function XXX(file,divName,functionToCall)
{
    $("#" + divName).load(file,null,function()
    {
        functionToCall();
    });
};
```

The HTML output of the PHP file:

`<div onClick="xxx(0,'xxx')" id="xxx"></div>`

Jquery converts it into:

`<div onClick="xxx(0,\'xxx\')" id="xxx"></div>`

Because of this convention I can't use the onClick function, it isn't valid any more. I can't figure out what I 'm doing wrong, does some one know what causes this problem and how to solve this in a good way? I already read other related question on Stack overflow, but I couldn't find an answer how to avoid escaping.

Comment: Check if `magic_quotes_gpc` is `on` on your server. http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

Comment: As i said, the html output isn't escaped. But Jquery converts it. You can read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745848/jquery-sending-data-with-escapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem isn't in a PHP block. Here are some rules you need to follow:

**For PHP use these rules:**

When to escape the char ' :

- When you want to use ' in a ' ' block. For example: echo 'test: \' this workes ';

When you don't need to escape the char ' :

- When you want to use ' in a “ ” block. For example: echo “test: '
  this workes “;

**For HTML use these rules:**
If you aren’t in a PHP block, then you don't need to escape data. The data you wrote here will directly be outputted. When you want to make a onClick, just use this template: `onClick”functionName('stringValue');”`

**Maybe it's because of the editor:**
Some editors will give \' an other color, don't let the colors distract you. It doesn't mean it's correct! Use a file editor with less features ( like notepad ) and open the PHP file where you were talking about. Check again if there are no \'s on places where they shouldn't be.

The problem isn't JQuery in this case. Trust me, look at the PHP file. Did you maybe escaped data outside a PHP block?

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with you PHP implementation not javascript. When PHP outputs your html it's set to escape quotes.

Comment: I checked the HTML output of the PHP file, it doesn't escape data.