# JS/PHP cross urlencoding and urldecoding

Tags: php, javascript, escaping, urlencode, urldecode

Alright I've been messing around with this for hours now and I still can't get it right so I'm gonna ask you guys.

I have a textarea in html, The value needs to be send to php using ajax(jquery) then imputed to the database, and printable again using php. The problem is i want when printing to be 100% the same as what you typed in. including characters like `'` and `\`

How I do it now:

```
var comment = escape( box.find('#newCommentArea').val() ).replace(new RegExp( "\\+", "g" ),"%2B");
```

Where `box.find('#newCommentArea').val()` is the value. I pass `comment` to php using ajax function and submit it as POST data.

using firebug this is what is appears to send: `comment=asdf%27asdf`

printing `$_POST['comment']` in php gives me `asdf\'asdf`

the added `\` is a problem. and i need to get rid of it.

either way because only javascript escape isn't safe in php i also do `urlencode()`

and when printing i use `rawurldecode()`

Could you guys point out if this method is good, or if it could be done better.

And how do i get rid of the new `\` in `$_POST['comment']`

Thanks in advance,

MakuraYami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slashes are automatically added, a setting of PHP or the server which can be changed (but usually shouldn't). You can reverse it using `stripslashes()` ([PHP: stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)). Use this function immediately before displaying, so not before storing in the database.

You don't need to urlencode in PHP anymore if it was already sent (the urlencode needs to be before sending), you just need to make sure it's database safe.

Unfortunately I can't advise you on what's the best way for URL encoding, I tend to get confused by it myself :) Hopefully someone else will be able to clarify that.

Comment: Alright this works pretty good, I think i was confused because i send a urlencoded string from javascript but in php it awsnt encoded anymore :/ Anyways using stripslashes works well it now displays the same as inputed!

Answer (score 1):

When you will print the text saved in the database, the `\'` will be displayed as `'`. So, it is ok to save into the database the value `\'`.

Further more, if you are using jQuery to make the request, you don't need to escape the `'` characters before the request, this should be packed up properly.

But, you do need to be careful to sanitize the text in PHP before saving it to database (use `mysql_real_escape_string` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php ).

Comment: Thanks, but do you really think I did not test how it was displayed? The \ stays when i print it, thats the problem. And mysql_real_escape_string give me errors, says it cannot find a connection, i alredy use PDO functions to protect against sql-injection.

Comment: I see. You could use `stripslashes` function before displaying the text, as Armatus suggested. If you are using PDO, you don't need to call `mysql_real_escape_string`. Regarding the javascript, I still recommend not to do the escaping manually.

Comment: I do the escape because when you submit string in javascript as POST using the & character will kill it, since it thinks the next var is made.

Comment: If you use jQuery to do the submit, you don't need to escape. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122298/how-to-properly-escape-html-sent-as-data-in-jquerys-ajax-function. The value is sent as a string value. Anyway, I am glad you made it work.